# HTML Validator confusion

Tags: html, validation

Still trying to get the hang of the questions format around here...

I'm trying to validate my HTML for my Web Design class... and to get full credit I need to have no errors.

I have checked it a million times and my validator swears that my `<head> </head>` is still open and I did not declare a DOCTYPE. I'm new at this so feel free to call me a noob.

This is the validator that I'm using: http://validator.w3.org/

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title> Wonder Penguin! </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="penguinicon.png"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="solo.css"/>
</head>

<img src= banner.jpg alt="Penguin!" />

<div id="content">
<div id="main" class="section">
<form action="solo.php" method="POST">
<h1> Personal Information </h1>
<label for="first_name">First Name:</label> <input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" />
<br>
<label for="last_name"> Last Name:</label> <input type="text" name="last_name" size="20" />
<br>
<label for="twitter">Twitter:</label><input type="text" name="twitter" size="20" />
<br>
<label for="website">Personal Website:</label><input type="text" name="website" size="20" />
<h1> Location </h1>
 State:<input type="Text" name="state" size="10" />
<br> 
City:  <input type="text" name="city" size="10" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Let's go!" size="80" /> 
<input type="reset" value="Start over?" size="80" /> 
</form>
</div>
<div id="column" class="section">

</div>


<div id="updates" class="section">
<h1> Updates </h1>

<p>
Hello!
</p>
</div>
<div id="aboutyou" class="section">

</div>
<div id="footer" class="section">
Footer is here! 
<br>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
printToday();
</script>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `<!DOCTYPE html>` string must be at the very start of the document to take effect. So move the `<html>` tag after it, or remove the `<html>` tag (it is not needed in HTML5, which is what you purport to comply with when you say `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

You will get a few other error messages then. Remove the `size` attribute from the submit button and the destruct (or “reset”) button – it is not allowed there and not recognized by browsers. (If you wish to set the width of the buttons, you can use the attribute `style="width: 80px"`, but don’t.) What is left then is a few “The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control” messages. Fix this by adding `id` attributes to the text input fields, e.g.

```
<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" size="20">
```

The `for` attribute value must match an `id` attribute value; `name` attributes are irrelevant here (but they are needed to name the fields so that their content gets sent in the form data).

(I dropped the `/` before `>`, because it is pointless – though permitted – in HTML serialization of HTML5. And it’s not good style to use it for some empty elements but not all.)

Answer (score 3):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` should be before  `<html>`

Answer (score 0):

Your DocType must be the first declaration of your file.  You can't put it inside the html tag.

So just inverse your DocType declaration with your html tag and you will be good.

Comment: The quotes are optional around an attribute value like `banner.jpg`.